# .htacces redirect all traffic to index.php and request for .js to another file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi Im Not very comfortable writing htaccess rules, my goal is

- Redirect all traffic to index.php
- Redirect all request to script.min.js to script.php

ultimately scripts.min.js does not exist rather the script.php will have set headers and include all needed JS files to create one master file. Also the status code should be 200.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it'd probably look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^script.min.js$ script.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]
```

Comment: This is redirecting everything to index.php including css files this is what i have which i took form the .htaccess WordPress generates  

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Technically that's what you asked for ("Redirect all traffic to index.php").... but glad you figured it out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by taking wordpress .htaccess and prepending the file match section

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        RewriteRule . /scripts.php [L]
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```